# Disable double-click event for a range when count of cells with date inputs reaches certain limits

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro that enters current date upon double-click:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F5:Q42")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Date
    End If                                                                                            
End Sub
```

I want to disable the click event for rows in the range when the COUNT of cells with date inputs reaches certain limits.

For example,
F5:Q5, I want to disable the click event (or cells otherwise unable to be actuated or date stamped) when four cells have values in them, so the macro cannot enter the date in a fifth cell.
F6:Q6 would see the macro disabled when 12 cells receive dates.
F7:Q7 would allow only 1 cell to be date stamped, and so on.

Like setting data validation limits on the double-click event.

Comment: What's the logic for the number of dates per row? 4, 12, 1... are these supposed to be hard-coded? Are there any other values (for example text) besides dates in each row?

Comment: @BigBen my method on such things is to use a named range. See below what OP is going for and drop a note if you can think of anything. I could build some arrays in code, but that would be a mess.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED Number II**

You just need to include some if-statements into your code. Below is an example that includes the requirement in your comment. You could condense my code with some `OR` statements but I wanted to illustrate exactly what was happening.

I put the ranges as `constants` at the top as I personally like to keep hardcoded items isolated.

**STRONG SUGGESTION:**

Rather than type out rows and range addresses in your VBA code that you *think* will ALWAYS be the ranges, why not setup some named ranges in Excel at the sheet level of each group (i.e. `Rng4`)? This will keep your VBA code dynamic so that if a goofy user comes in (maybe YOU if you're in a hurry!) and inserts a row or deletes a row, your code remains funcional. In my opinion, this is the #1 reason VBA code "breaks" and newbies get frustrated; they are used to excel automagically updating rows/columns modifications and forget that their VBA hard coded members won't do this. However, this is resolved with a names range.

Regardless, here is a specific answer to your question:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Const Rng4_a As String = "F5:Q10"
Const Rng4_b As String = "F12:Q15"
Const Rng12_a As String = "F16:Q22"
Const Rng12_b As String = "F25:Q30"
Dim doYourThing As Boolean



    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Rng4_a)) Is Nothing And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Intersect(Range(Rng4_a), Target.EntireRow)) < 4 Then
            doYourThing = True

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range(Rng4_b)) Is Nothing And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Intersect(Range(Rng4_b), Target.EntireRow)) < 4 Then
            doYourThing = True

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range(Rng12_a)) Is Nothing And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Intersect(Range(Rng12_a), Target.EntireRow)) < 12 Then
            doYourThing = True

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range(Rng12_b)) Is Nothing And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Intersect(Range(Rng12_b), Target.EntireRow)) < 12 Then
            doYourThing = True

    End If


    If doYourThing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Date
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a couple of signs flipped, and missed the part about the row, but I think this should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much--your solution works great. Follow-up: how do I add ranges to the code.  I fooled around with it for a while, but kept getting compile errors.   So, I have multiple ranges (all F:Q) with different arguments. For example,

Comment: For example...F5:Q10 and F12:Q15 would be <4, but F16:Q22 and F25:!30 are < 12. How would those different ranges and conditions be represented within the code?  Sorry I wasn't clear in my original request.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you PGSystem Tester.  While the code enters the date when I double-click, when I test it by doing another (to test the limitation to only one date stamp entry) I get an error.  So, in the range of the spreadsheet that's limited to 1 date stamp, when I double-click a second time, I get an error instead of just double-clicking into the cell with no data stamp actuating from the code.

Comment: @VBANewb sorry, I don't understand. Maybe rephrase your question or list example.